# NGINX shared server variables

Tags: nginx

In NGINX when setting up my different servers, I find that I have a lot of duplicate settings. For example, this setting returns in each separate server:

```
location ~ \.php {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
```

Is there a way to make this global, so that it is shared with different servers?

Answer (score 2):

yes you could create a file in your nginx folder called say

phpcommon.conf

which could contain those elements

and in the nginx config block where they originally were you would have a line

`include /etc/nginx/phpcommon.conf;`